# jQuery trigger press enter not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my script:

```
$('.target input').val('my value');
$('.target input').trigger(jQuery.Event('keypress', { keycode: 13 }));
```

The first line worked and the value set correctly, then I need to press the enter in input element, but the second line not worked. I mean the event not fired:

```
$('.target input').keyup(function(e){
      if(e.keyCode == 13)
      {
            alert($(this).val());
      }
 });
```

when I press the enter manually the event fires but with javascript the event not fired. where is the problem?

Comment: what you mean by not working ?

Comment: @PranavCBalan I updated the question

Comment: When you hit enter, what are you trying to get to happen?  Form Submit?  Right now, you're triggering an event that will only fire if you have a separate listener configured.  If you're trying to submit a form, just $('formselector').submit()

Answer (score 2):

You need to trigger `keyup` event in order to fire keyup event handler. Although the property `keycode` should be changed to [`keyCode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode) since object property is case sensitive Javascript.

```
$('.target input').trigger(jQuery.Event('keyup', { keyCode: 13 }));
```

```js
$('.target input').keyup(function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 13) {
    alert($(this).val());
  }
});

$('.target input').val('my value');
$('.target input').trigger(jQuery.Event('keyup', {
  keyCode: 13
}));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="target">
  <input/>
</div>
```

**FYI :** You need to bind event handler before the event triggering with the code, otherwise it won't listen to the event triggered before the listener is attached.

Although object properties passing on [`jQuery.Event`](https://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/) supports  1.6 onwards, so check your jQuery version.

> As of jQuery 1.6, you can also pass an object to [jQuery.Event()](https://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/) and its properties will be set on the newly created Event object.

Comment: I think you are binding event handler after triggering the event... can you reproduce the problem in stacksnippet or http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: that's not the problem,

Comment: @Saeid : which version are you  using?

Answer (score 0):

```
var e = jQuery.Event("keydown");
e.which = 13;
$(".target input").trigger(e);
```

Comment: it will be nice if you give an explanation, what's wrong with the question, what the solution do.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the work for you,

```
  var e = jQuery.Event("keypress");
    e.which = 13; //choose the one you want
    e.keyCode = 13;
    $("#theInputToTest").trigger(e);
```

Answer (score 0):

**[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/y6xj0dre/2/)**

Basically you need to trigger `keyup` event as I did in the fiddle.

**HTML**

```
<input type=text />
```

**JS**

```
$(":input").keyup(function(e){
  if(e.which==13){
    alert("Fired");
  }
});

$(":input").val("TEST");
$(":input").trigger($.Event("keyup",{which:13}));
```